# How To Search For A String In Python In A Changed Log File?

Tags: python, full-text-search

I'm trying to use python to search for errors in my logs and I'm using the attached code.
My problem is that It keeps popping since it always finds the same "error" in the log. 
I actually want it to pop only once per match, as the log keeps filling.

```
import mmap
import socket
import ctypes   

# get hostname
machine_name=(socket.gethostname())

f = open('c:\\path\to\myfile'+machine_name+'.log')
s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
if s.find('ERROR') != -1:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "ERROR Has Been Found", "Error", 1)
```

Comment: I assume like a ideal log file , your's will also have timestamp, Try to filter the old log string with timestamp. I mean take current time and use some logic to get how long you want to filter the log. it will get you recent one based on your condition.